# Material UI Slide component - how to disable Slide Effect based on component state

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a menu that is encapsulated in a Slide component. The code is this:

```
 return(


    <Slide direction="down" in={showNavState} >
      <AppBar position="absolute" className={classes.bgColor} >
        <Toolbar>
              <Button className={classes.saveDataButton} color="inherit">SAVE MY DATA</Button>
              <Button color="inherit" onClick ={redirectToClientsList}>My Clients</Button> 
              <Button color="inherit" onClick ={redirectToCalendar}>Calendar</Button>

        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>

    </Slide>

)
```

I am using indexDB to show the above (navigation) code when a user enters some data into a form for the first time. When the user enters the data it is stored to a useState instance in React.

user adds data---> useState updates to TRUE --> show nav code

When the nav code is shown it "slides" down (and looks neat) and is what I want.

When a user goes to another page it continues to "slide down" on each page load. I do not want this.

The only solution I have come up with is to return the Nav code without the Slide based on a different useState value. In other words something like this:

```
if(someState){

    return(

    // With Slide

    <Slide direction="down" in={showNavState} >
      <AppBar position="absolute" className={classes.bgColor} >
        <Toolbar>
              <Button className={classes.saveDataButton} color="inherit">SAVE MY DATA</Button>
              <Button color="inherit" onClick ={redirectToClientsList}>My Clients</Button> 
              <Button color="inherit" onClick ={redirectToCalendar}>Calendar</Button>

        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>

    </Slide>

)


}else{

 return(

  // Without Slide

      <AppBar position="absolute" className={classes.bgColor} >
        <Toolbar>
              <Button className={classes.saveDataButton} color="inherit">SAVE MY DATA</Button>
              <Button color="inherit" onClick ={redirectToClientsList}>My Clients</Button> 
              <Button color="inherit" onClick ={redirectToCalendar}>Calendar</Button>

        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>



)



}
```

Question: Is there a way to show the contents of the Slide component statically without any animation? This way I could just set the value based on a useState boolean (or some other value).

Like this:

```
<Slide direction="none" in={showNavState} >
  // shows content statically
</Slide>
```

**EDIT:**

I added a codesandbox example per a request in a comment below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-bird-3f7ir

Also, I figure I could do this with a Context instance, but it seems like overkill.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) that reproduces your problem. I think the root cause is likely to be in code outside of the code you've shown. The animation should only occur when the value of the `in` property changes.

Comment: I will have to set up React router in codesandbox. I will say that even when I pass in a TRUE  from the router the Slide...... it still "slides" on ever page load.

Comment: @RyanCogswell   Here you go: https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-bird-3f7ir

Comment: Your sandbox doesn’t currently provide any way to reproduce the problem — it doesn’t provide any way to navigate to a different page (the scenario that presumably triggers an undesirable slide animation).

Comment: @RyanCogswell I added a link to click

Comment: I don’t see anything different.

Comment: Either you forgot to save your changes, or the changes were saved to a different url (which you didn’t provide).

Comment: @RyanCogswell I redid it and chose "save all" in codesandbox. Hopefully it saved this time

Comment: If you use a new browser for the changes, it will save the changes to a new url. You need to provide that new url.

Comment: Here's a version of your sandbox that I added a couple links to. The slide transition works fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/slide-with-nav-c1vq2.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Slide direction="down" in={showNavState} appear={false}>
```

This may do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show Slide on the bases of value of `someState`, there is a sort way to do this like:

```
render(){
  var appBar = (
    <AppBar position="absolute" className={classes.bgColor} >
      <Toolbar>
        <Button className={classes.saveDataButton} color="inherit">SAVE MY DATA</Button>
        <Button color="inherit" onClick ={redirectToClientsList}>My Clients</Button> 
        <Button color="inherit" onClick ={redirectToCalendar}>Calendar</Button>
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
  )
  var withSlideBar = (
    <Slide direction="down" in={showNavState} >
      {appBar}    
    </Slide>
  )
  return (
    <div>{ someState ? withSlideBar : appBar }</div>
  )
}
```

Comment: That's what I did in my above code. Set a conditional.